# Passing Multiple Refs from Child Component to Parent Component-Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have two components, the *Edit*(child) and the *Index*(parent).
There are three input boxes in the *Edit* component and I'll like to:

1. Pass these three refs to the *Index* component
2. Compare these inputs gotten via refs (in the HandleUpdate function specifically)

**Edit.js**:

```js
<form onSubmit={props.handleUpdate}>
        <input 
            className=""
            name="name" 
            ref={props.setRef}                          
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            defaultValue= {props.name} /> 
        <input 
            className=""
            type="number" 
            name="day"
            min="1" 
            max="31"
            ref={props.setRef}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            defaultValue= {props.day}  />
        <input 
            className=""
            name="dob"
            type="month"    
            ref={props.setRef}                          
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            defaultValue={props.dob} />
```

**Index.js**:

```js
class BirthdaylistKeeper extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
   //state
}
...
handleUpdate(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
            //if((name.value === "") && (dob.value === "") && (day.value === "")){
            //  console.log("empty");
            //}

            const item = this.state.currentItem;
            let index = this.state.items.indexOf(item);
            const newItemList = [...this.state.items];
            newItemList.splice(index, 1, this.state.dataEdited);

            this.setState({ 
                items: [...newItemList],
                toggle: false 
            });

    }   
//...
render(){
        return(
            ...
                <Entry
                    name={this.state.name}
                    day={this.state.day}
                    dob={this.state.dob}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                    setRef={this.setRef} /> 

)
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea, instead of passing *refs* from child to parent, make the refs in the parent and pass them to the child component and then assign them to each input element, something like the following codes:

The parent component:

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

class BirthdaylistKeeper extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.nameRef = createRef();
    this.dayRef = createRef();
    this.dobRef = createRef();

   //state
  }

  ~~~

  render() {
    return(

      ~~~

      <Entry
        nameRef={this.nameRef}
        dayRef={this.dayRef}
        dobRef={this.dobRef}
  }
}
```

And in the child component pass each ref to the related input element:

```js
<form onSubmit={props.handleUpdate}>
  <input
    ~~~
    name="name"
    ~~~
    ref={props.nameRef}
    ~~~
  /> 
  <input
    ~~~
    name="day"
    ~~~
    ref={props.dayRef}
    ~~~
  />
  <input
    ~~~
    name="dob"
    ~~~
    ref={props.dobRef}
    ~~~
  />
```

Also, remember you should use separated refs for each input elements, not using one to all of them.

Comment: How can I access the ref values in the handleUpdate function in index.js?

Comment: @henrie, your comment shows you even didn't see the ReactJS doc about `ref`. it is simple, try one of those three by using `this.nameRef.current`.

Comment: I actually went tthrough the Docs and I logged  ```this.nameRef.current``` to console but didnt get the expected result..Here is result I got this  ```<input class="" name="dob" type="month" value="2020-04">```, that is why I had to ask

Comment: @henrie, what do you expect? what do you wanna see in your console log? it is the exactly right thing.

Comment: oww!..I think I get it now, Thanks for your help